# React.JS Call childs component method from Parent Wrapper Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on React application and making something like a framework where I have a wrapper component some thing like this.

```
class FrameworkComponent extends React.Component {
  someFunction() {
    // send data to child data using childs function
    // something like this.some.thing.childFunction("mydata");
    ...
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <div><button onClick={this.someFunction}>Click me</button></div>
        <div>{this.props.child}</div>
       </div>
     )
  } 
}
```

and using it like this :

```
class SecondComponent extends React.Component {
  childFunction(dataRecived) {
    alert(dataRecived);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>;
  }
}

import FrameworkComponent from '../FrameworkComponent';
import SecondComponent from '../SecondComponent';

class OtherComponet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FrameworkComponent>
          <div><SecondComponent /></div>
        </FrameworkComponent>
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

So here I want child's component receive data from parent wrapper component either by updating its child props : `componentWillReceiveProps()` or calling its child method.

Comment: Usually you pass data to a child component using its props. What type of data do you want to pass to it? How much data are you passing?

Comment: @Ben Smith I want a calendar component in my framework so whenever date is selected all or one of my child gets updated date.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use HOC - Higher - https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html